# Explicit formula for matrix operator norms

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

On the $n$-dimensional vector space $K^n$, we have the well known norms $\Vert\cdot\Vert_p,1\leq p\leq \infty$, and a linear operator in $\mathcal{L}(K^n)$ can be identified with a matrix $A\in M_n(K)$.

We can define the following operator norms:
$$\Vert A\Vert_1:=\sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\Vert Ax\Vert_1}{\Vert x\Vert_1},$$
$$\Vert A\Vert_2:=\sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\Vert Ax\Vert_2}{\Vert x\Vert_2},$$
$$\Vert A\Vert_{\infty}:=\sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\Vert Ax\Vert_{\infty}}{\Vert x\Vert_{\infty}}.$$

And it is not difficult to derive explicit formulas for the operator norms above:
$$\Vert A\Vert_1=\max_{1\leq j\leq n}\sum_{i=1}^n |a_{ij}|,$$
$$\Vert A\Vert_2=\rho(A^*A)^{1/2},$$
$$\Vert A\Vert_{\infty}=\max_{1\leq i\leq n}\sum_{j=1}^n |a_{ij}|.$$

More general, we have other operator norms defined by
$$\sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\Vert Ax\Vert_p}{\Vert x\Vert_q}, 1\leq p,q\leq \infty.$$
I have trouble in finding explicit formulas for these norms, I guess that the formula may be the "$L_{p,q}$" norm defined by
$$\Vert A\Vert_{p,q}=\Big(\sum_j \big(\sum_i |a_ij|^p\big)^{q/p}\Big)^{1/q}.$$
Any help?

> Edit: Thanks to Klaus' answer, the general cases may be too hard to handle. However, can we derive explicit formulas for the "special" cases when $1\leq p<\infty,q=1$ and $p=\infty,1\leq q<\infty$ ?

Answer (score 5):

There is no easy formula for these norms. In fact, computing $p$-norms is [NP-hard](https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.1397).

EDIT: For $p = \infty$ and arbitrary $q$, you need to maximize the inner product of the rows of $A$ with your vector $x$. By $L^p$-duality, the maximum is exactly the $q'$-Norm (where $\frac{1}{q} + \frac{1}{q'} = 1$) of the row. Thus, if I am not mistaken, you'd get
$$\|A\|_{p,q} = \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} \left(\sum\limits_{j = 1}^n |a_{i,j}|^{q'}\right)^{\frac{1}{q'}}.$$
Of course, if $q = 1$, the sum needs to be replaced by a maximum. By $L^p$-duality again, you then also get
$$\|A\|_{p,q} = \max_{1 \leq j \leq n} \left(\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n |a_{i,j}|^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$
for $q = 1$ and arbitrary $p$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But are there explicit formulas for the cases $q=1,1\leq p<\infty$ and $p=\infty,1\leq q<\infty$ ?

Comment: @SRA I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your time!