# Matrix norm from $L_p$ to $L_q$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-norms

I am looking into the [matrix norm $\|\cdot\|_{p,q}, p,q\ge1$, induced by vector norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Matrix_norms_induced_by_vector_norms). I am having trouble deriving the explicit expression for the matrix norm in terms of the matrix elements.

For matrix $A:=[a_{i,j}]_{i,j}$ and a column matrix $x:=[x_j]_j$,
\begin{align}
\|Ax\|_q &= \bigg(\sum_i\Big|\sum_j a_{i,j}x_j\Big|^q\bigg)^\frac1q \\
&\le \sum_j \Big(\sum_i |a_{i,j}x_j|^q \Big)^\frac1q \quad \text{ by Minkowski's inequality} \tag1\label1\\
&=\sum_j |x_j|\Big(\sum_i |a_{i,j}|^q\Big)^\frac1q \\
&\le \Big(\sum_j |x_j|^p\Big)^\frac1p\bigg(\sum_j\Big(\sum_i |a_{i,j}|^q\Big)^\frac{p'}q\bigg)^\frac1{p'}  \quad\text{by Hölder's inequality}  \tag2\label2
\end{align}
where $p'$ is the Hölder conjugate so that $\frac1p+\frac1{p'}=1$. So I would think
$$\|A\|_{p,q}=\bigg(\sum_j\Big(\sum_i |a_{i,j}|^q\Big)^\frac{p'}q\bigg)^\frac1{p'}. \tag3\label3$$
The part I am not sure is how I would simultaneously make inequalities \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} equalities in order to prove the upper bound of \eqref{2} is reachable.

However, [this Wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#L2,1_and_Lp,q_norms) indicates that
$$\| A \|_{p,q} =  \left(\sum_{j=1}^n \left( \sum_{i=1}^m |a_{i,j}|^p \right)^{\frac{q}{p}}\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}$$
quite different from Equation \eqref{3}. **Note: As pointed out by @QiaochuYuan in the comments below, this matrix norm notation is overloaded and symbolizes a different norm from the induced matrix norm defined above. We should correct the notation.**

What is the correct derivation of $\| A \|_{p,q}$?

Comment: Are you trying to estimate $\sup_{\|x\|_p=1}\|Ax\|_q$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explicit formula for matrix operator norms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4547306/explicit-formula-for-matrix-operator-norms)

Comment: @OliverDíaz: Yes, as is indicated in the question.

Comment: Wikipedia is describing a different norm there, that's not the $L^p$ to $L^q$ operator norm, which is much harder to calculate even when $p = q = 2$.

Comment: @Klaus: It does not seem to. The expressions there are different from either of the two expressions I have in the question. There is no derivation there either.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I have two Wikipedia references. Which one are you referring to? Is it the second reference?

Comment: @Hans There is no explicit formula for these vector norms if $p,q \notin \{1,2,\infty\}$.

Comment: The second one, yes. It's just a different norm.

Comment: @Klaus: Ah, I see.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I see. That Wikipedia section then should not have used the same matrix norm notation as that in the previous section defining the induced matrix norm. It is very confusing.

Comment: @Hans: Wikipedia can be edited.

Comment: @OliverDíaz: Good idea. I made the first attempt in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#L2,1_and_Lp,q_norms . I suggest we use a different notation for that norm there. But I have not come up with a good one yet.